# INDEX/MATCH with multiple criteria in rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets, match

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets. In `SheetA` I have 3 rows and 3 columns for each userId.
In `SheetB` I have the same dataset but 9 rows and 1 column for each userId. How do I bring the Answer values from `SheetA` (from columns "`Answer1`", "`Answer2`", "`Answer3`") in `SheetB` (in the column "Value")? The difficulty is in matching multiple criteria (not just the the userId, but also the stepId and Attribute/Answer)

Here is an exemplary Google Sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iOeqpMHL6q_aFkVw9il039jGKHhbu6xxZLZrN0LXcEc/edit?usp=sharing

I think it is a combination of `INDEX/MATCH` and `HLOOKUP` but I can't figure it out. Anyone has any ideas?

SheetA:

| userId | stepName | stepId | Answer1 | Answer2 | Answer3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 126 | StepA | 20 | 50 | 20 | 10 |
| 131 | StepA | 20 | 20 | 23 | 23 |
| 133 | StepA | 20 | 32 | 80 | 50 |
| 134 | StepA | 20 | 60 | 46 | 23 |
| 138 | StepA | 20 | 12 | 45 | 67 |
| 139 | StepA | 20 | 50 | 20 | 10 |
| 142 | StepA | 20 | 20 | 23 | 23 |
| 144 | StepA | 20 | 32 | 80 | 50 |
| 147 | StepA | 20 | 60 | 46 | 23 |
| 126 | StepB | 30 | 12 | 45 | 67 |
| 131 | StepB | 30 | 50 | 20 | 10 |
| 133 | StepB | 30 | 20 | 23 | 23 |
| 134 | StepB | 30 | 32 | 80 | 50 |
| 138 | StepB | 30 | 60 | 46 | 23 |
| 139 | StepB | 30 | 12 | 45 | 67 |
| 142 | StepB | 30 | 50 | 20 | 10 |
| 144 | StepB | 30 | 20 | 23 | 23 |
| 147 | StepB | 30 | 32 | 80 | 50 |
| 126 | StepC | 40 | 60 | 46 | 23 |
| 131 | StepC | 40 | 12 | 45 | 67 |
| 133 | StepC | 40 | 50 | 20 | 10 |
| 134 | StepC | 40 | 20 | 23 | 23 |
| 138 | StepC | 40 | 32 | 80 | 50 |
| 139 | StepC | 40 | 60 | 46 | 23 |
| 142 | StepC | 40 | 12 | 45 | 67 |
| 144 | StepC | 40 | 32 | 80 | 50 |
| 147 | StepC | 40 | 12 | 45 | 67 |

SheetB:

| userId | stepName | stepId | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 126 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 126 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 126 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 126 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 126 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 126 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 126 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 126 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 126 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 131 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 131 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 131 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 131 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 131 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 131 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 131 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 131 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 131 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 133 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 133 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 133 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 133 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 133 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 133 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 133 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 133 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 133 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 134 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 134 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 134 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 134 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 134 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 134 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 134 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 134 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 134 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 138 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 138 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 138 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 138 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 138 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 138 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 138 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 138 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 138 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 139 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 139 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 139 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 139 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 139 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 139 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 139 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 139 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 139 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 142 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 142 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 142 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 142 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 142 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 142 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 142 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 142 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 142 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 144 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 144 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 144 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 144 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 144 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 144 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 144 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 144 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 144 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |
| 147 | StepA | 20 | Answer3 | ? |
| 147 | StepA | 20 | Answer2 | ? |
| 147 | StepA | 20 | Answer1 | ? |
| 147 | StepB | 30 | Answer3 | ? |
| 147 | StepB | 30 | Answer2 | ? |
| 147 | StepB | 30 | Answer1 | ? |
| 147 | StepC | 40 | Answer3 | ? |
| 147 | StepC | 40 | Answer2 | ? |
| 147 | StepC | 40 | Answer1 | ? |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, 
 {SheetA!A:A&SheetA!B:B&SheetA!C:C, SheetA!D:F}, 
 IF(D2:D=SheetA!D1, 2, 
 IF(D2:D=SheetA!E1, 3, 
 IF(D2:D=SheetA!F1, 4, ))), 0)))
```

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, 
 {SheetA!A:A&SheetA!B:B&SheetA!C:C, SheetA!D:F}, 
 MATCH(D2:D, SheetA!D1:F1, 0)+1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Works really well :)